# How do I find the module for a given cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

How do I determine the module for a given cmdlet for direct calling from a function that overrides the cmdlet?

For example, how am I supposed to find out that Start-Transcript lives in Microsoft.Powershell.Host?

```
Get-Module Start-Transcript
```

doesn't yield anything

---

Update for answer below.

This is the output:

```
PS C:\Windows> Get-Command -type cmdlet start-transcript | fl *

HelpUri             : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113408
DLL                 : C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft
                      .PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll
Verb                : Start
Noun                : Transcript
HelpFile            : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll-Help.xml
PSSnapIn            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host
ImplementingType    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand
Definition          : Start-Transcript [[-Path] <String>] [-Append] [-Force] [-NoClobber] [-Verbose] [-Debug] [-ErrorAc
                      tion <ActionPreference>] [-WarningAction <ActionPreference>] [-ErrorVariable <String>] [-WarningV
                      ariable <String>] [-OutVariable <String>] [-OutBuffer <Int32>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]

DefaultParameterSet :
OutputType          : {}
Name                : Start-Transcript
CommandType         : Cmdlet
Visibility          : Public
ModuleName          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host <------------ HERE IT IS
Module              :
Parameters          : {[Path, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [Append, System.Management.Automation.Pa
                      rameterMetadata], [Force, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [NoClobber, System.Man
                      agement.Automation.ParameterMetadata]...}
ParameterSets       : {[[-Path] <String>] [-Append] [-Force] [-NoClobber] [-Verbose] [-Debug] [-ErrorAction <ActionPref
                      erence>] [-WarningAction <ActionPreference>] [-ErrorVariable <String>] [-WarningVariable <String>
                      ] [-OutVariable <String>] [-OutBuffer <Int32>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use

```
Get-Command Start-Transcript | fl *
```

to find information about the command.

Comment: There's a ModuleName property that doesn't show up in the default table of get-command. (Look for ModuleName : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host)

Comment: This works better: get-command -type cmdlet start-transcript | select ModuleName

Comment: A more succinct version: `(Get-Command Start-Transcript).ModuleName`

Comment: This is the correct answer, but while remoting into Office 365 and using the exported cmdlets, I get: `ModuleName: tmp_w2zqg2rv.5j3` - how helpful...

Answer (score 12):

There are a few options in PowerShell. In order to narrow result to a specific information you're looking for - one of the following approaches can be used:

```
(Get-Command -Name Start-Transcript).ModuleName
```

or

```
Get-Command -Name Start-Transcript | Select-Object -Property ModuleName
```

or

```
Get-Command -Name Start-Transcript | Format-List -Property ModuleName
```

Note:

It is generally considered a good practice to use a full cmdlet name instaed of alias (like fl, ft, select etc.) whenever you use it within PowerShell script or develop a custom PowerShell module. It increases your code readability.

Comment: I would argue that it massively *decreases* code readability to use the long-form of cmdlets in scripts. Considering that things like iex and fl and ft have now existing for more than 13 years, I think it is good practive to *always* use aliases (with 13+ years heritage) than to write out very confusing long-form code in every script. I would also argue to never use custom aliases (except those defined within a given script) but for core aliases: always use these whenever possible to increase code readability (just to keep in mind that aliases with 13 years heritage are pretty reliable).

Comment: One of the principle states that code should be self-documenting, see:  http://shorturl.at/cC289 Aliases defeats that purpose. It is generally a BAD idea to use them in the scripts, there were designed and should be used mainly for ad hoc commands. Someone might argue that experienced users might embrace build-in aliases as long as they stay consistent in their scripting habits. However, sharing such a code again makes it less clear and harder to understand by the community.

Comment: Nowadays when there are good editors like VSCode with auto-completion, IntelliSense features build-in, typing full cmdlet name is not an issue and it is generally considered as a best practice in PowerShell world.

Comment: I strongly recommend to not use built in aliases and it is a VERY BAD idea to not use the built in aliases in scripts as they have been unchanged for over 13 years. i.e. this is a best practice in the same way that "brushing your teeth 30 times a day", or "never drinking alcohol" might be considered "best practices". You *could* do those things... or you could try and function without OCD and just approach life in the world in a sane and rational way without taking hatred-of-aliases to absurd levels. Use aliases. Do not acquire OCD. Ignore the doomsayers, they are just repeating.

Comment: @YorSubs Aliases haven't been unchanged, though. For example, `Set-Content` was aliased `sc` pre PowerShell Core. In Core, `sc` runs Service Control Manager. There's no guarantee that more aliases won't be removed or changed since Microsoft considers them just a convenience for the REPL. Better to follow their recommendation since they make changes based on it.